# Forwarding web services through JMS

Tags: web-services, jms, java-metro-framework, forwarding

I'm trying to figure out how to forward web service requests from the web server to a remote application server through jms.
In my architecture there are web services client which communicate with some web server (Tomcat) which needs to forward the request to be executed on a remote application server and at the end get the result and push it back to the web service client.
Something like:
Web Service Client <-> HTTP <-> Tomcat <-> JMS <-> Application Server.
I want to use jax-ws so my methods will be called automatically in the application server.
Although I've expected this will be common approach, I didn't find any examples.
I would appreciate if someone can provide some links or tips on how such a configuration can be built.
Currently I'm using Metro but any other solution is valid as well.
Another aspect which I'm interested in, is whether I can use the fast-infoset over JMS to increase performance.
Thanks in advance,
  Avner

Comment: Please look on this question. Please guide me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/jersey-rest-web-service-with-activemq-middleware-integration. Thankd for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to solve it is using [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/).

Then you can configure such a thing with an XML configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

you can try wso2MB as a JMS provider ...Check following links, would be useful

[1]http://wso2.org/library/message-broker

[2]http://pzf.fremantle.org/2011/04/introduction-to-wso2-message-broker_05.html

Comment: @Ratha, Please see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/jersey-rest-web-service-with-activemq-middleware-integration
Thanks for your time.